# Probability for guessing answers

Tags: probability

The question :  There are 2 True or False questions and 1 multiple choice question, it is given that Bob answers the multiple choice question correctly, find the probability of two answers correct in total.
Why isnt it 1/4×1/2=1/8?
Why should the answer be 2/4=1/2?

Comment: you know the multiple choice answer is correct - its probability of being correct is 1! That just leaves one correct answer out of two.

Answer (score 1):

Bob has a total fo correct answers of 2 if and only if he answers correctly one of the True/False questions, and is wrong to the other, since he has the correct answer to the multiple choice questions.

This can be achieved in two ways:

- Correct to the first T/F question and wrong to the second one. This occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{4}$
- Wrong to the first, correct to the second. This also occurs with probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

Finally, he has a probability of $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$ to have exactly two correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can ignore the multiple choice question completely because he got it right.

Then the answer is just the probability of getting exactly one T/F question right (since we are already given 1 right answer - the multiple choice).  Which we can compute directly or subtract the probabilities of getting both right and both wrong from 1.

Hence $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

We don't know for sure the probability cuz you didn't specify if Bob is guessing at the T/F questions or has some knowledge of them.  Maybe he has a history of getting those right 75% of the time but we don't know.